# CSS tooltip with opacity=1 doesn't cover links

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm facing a weird issue with tooltip in my website.

I render an AJAX datatable in one of the pages, and under some column I have a list of links which
show some info when the user hovers over them.
Now the tooltip background covers adjacent text, but not adjacent links - they "penetrate" the background:

[Background covers adjacent text - as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHlDi.png)

[Adjacent link penetrates the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI6Oi.png)

Links' HTML element:

```
<a class="tooltip" href="http://some.url.com/browse/${dmpItem["id"]}" target="_blank" data-text="${dmpItem["name"]}">${dmpItem["id"]}</a> - ${dmpItem["status"]}
```

My CSS code:

```
.tooltip {
    position:relative;
}

.tooltip:before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    top: 160%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #323254;
    color: #dadae0;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border:10px solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #323254 transparent;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip:hover:before, .tooltip:hover:after {
    opacity: 1 !important ;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

So opacity is 1 and I even added the "important" flag after googling similar issues, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding z-index to your .tooltip:before make a difference?

```
.tooltip:before, .tooltip:after {
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Sometimes position: absolute can be really funky and have strange overlapping problems with things like links, or anything that has display: inline as its default or added to it.

Alternatively, changing the pseudo-selectors (:before) to pseudo-elements (::before) could also impact the functionality of the pop-up.